# can someone help me with this gridview and fancybox?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, fancybox

i have a button in a gridview and i cant put in the buttonfield class so i can call the fancybox can someone help me with some options?

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
        CssClass="table table-bordered bs-table"

    allowpaging="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableModelValidation="True"> 
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FE2E2E" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="white" /> 
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Nombre" ControlStyle-Width="70px" >
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FechaNac" HeaderText="FechaNac" SortExpression="FechaNac" >
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Teléfono Casa" HeaderText="Teléfono Casa" SortExpression="Teléfono Casa" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Teléfono Celular" HeaderText="Teléfono Celular" SortExpression="Teléfono Celular" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Edad" HeaderText="Edad" SortExpression="Edad" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Estatus" HeaderText="Estatus" SortExpression="Estatus" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Atendido por" HeaderText="Atendido por" SortExpression="Atendido por" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"  />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: are you using jquery fancybox ? and you want to put it on the grid itself or  button for each row ?

Comment: want to put it only in the button just to call some info of that row i have the code for the fancybox but when i try to call it with a class in the buttonfield the fancybox dont appear i think commandname in buttonfield its wrong when i use it

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add it on select command add DatosCiudadanos class to your button field :

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn glyphicon glyphicon-earphone DatosCiudadanos"  />
```

add provide the aspx page in href property :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".DatosCiudadanos").
              fancybox(
              {
                  'autoScale': false,
                  'transitionIn': 'none',
                  'transitionOut': 'none', 'width': 680,
                  'height': 450,
                  'type': 'iframe',
                  'href': "/youraspxpage.aspx"
              }
              );
     });
</script>
```

Comment: i had this to call the fancybox       <script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".DatosCiudadanos").fancybox({  
        'autoScale'     : false,  
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',  
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',  
        'width'         : 680,  
        'height'        : 450,  
        'type'          : 'iframe'  
    });  
});

Comment: just to call another aspx that i made

Comment: Check the updated answer please you just need to add the correct class to the button field which is DatosCiudadanos

Comment: and in the script i need to put from where i need to call the aspx?

Comment: add href property to the function see updated answer with new javascript